# AES 256 Encryption of a column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, encryption, aes

I am trying to do an AES-256 bit encryption in R. This is to be done for a column of a dataframe. Eg.,
df:-

```
  **fname   lname  city   country**
    aas     das    Mum      IN
    asdw    gup    del      IN
    erf     fre    Sfo      US ...
```

in this data frame, i need to encrypt the first 2 fields and store the encrypted values instead, in the dataframe.
Currently i am using the code :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
  {
    ip <- charToRaw(df$name[i])
    enc <- PKI.encrypt(ip, key)
    enc ->df$ip[i]
 }
```

Here, I am essentially trying to encrypt all entries of the 'Name' field in a loop and trying to store it back in the df.
However in doing so, i am concerned about the following:
1. an example of the encrypted value is as below:

```
14 5e 9d 27 e8 6d cd d0 f3 1a 8d 50 6c 8c be a9 12 f4 43 92 0a 44 8a 50 cb be 15 44 23 2a 37 8b fa 8c 8e 5c c5 67 61 81 d5 22 dc fa c3 47 4a 22 76 34 dd 4c
aa e9 ae a0 d0 48 bf 28 f6 fc f4 94 0f 0b 10 d6 e7 84 94 6a a6 60 da 4e f6 56 9a b2 6a 54 11 0e f4 bf f1 2b c1 5a 18 14 e4 d1 58 a9 22 6f 08 c2 fe c8 13 0d
4c 58 a7 bd 96 e8 9e e3 76 80 95 c4 3f e1 16 48 aa aa ef 57 2a 69 4f 45 a0 0a 80 3c 95 f8 06 1b 46 ee f5 ed 8a 29 7d aa f7 73 90 f7 2c 93 4e c9 34 f5 20 6b
38 45 87 49 37 f0 29 9e 4e 53 a6 52 af 51 56 07 13 3c 68 bc cf de bc 88 ac 5e 36 4a 01 d0 19 50 53 49 c0 78 b2 c8 b3 df b8 fa 2b a1 8d 3c 25 a8 fa 9f fd ee
ab c6 ff ff 36 6c 65 db bd 0d 40 2d 96 c1 da 85 f2 07 4f 2a 4b 2d c6 a8 ad 29 e7 28 8b ac 56 91 a5 73 ec 24 da 56 ba 13 95 09 54 77 a0 6e 74 90
```

Is this the kind of output expected in AES 256??

2. When trying to store the values in the df, it just stored the 1st component, i.e. 14, considering the above example. How can the entire value be stored in the respective rows??

Thanks!!

Comment: One thing you can do is to use a list to hold the cyphertext `list(enc) -> df$ip[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a for loop, you can use `map` from the `purrr` package. `map` can store the result in your dataframe as a list.

```
library(PKI)
library(purrr)
key <- PKI.genRSAkey(2048)

# create some helper functions
encrypt <- function(x){
  # function assumes you already created a RSA key called key
  x <- charToRaw(x)
  e <- PKI.encrypt(x, key)
  return(e)
}

decrypt <- function(x) {
  # function assumes you already have a key called key
  e <- PKI.decrypt(x, key)
  x <- rawToChar(e)
  return(x)
}

#  encrypt the first name
df$ip <- map(df$fname, encrypt)

str(df)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ fname  : chr  "aas" "asdw" "erf"
 $ lname  : chr  "das" "gup" "fre"
 $ city   : chr  "Mum" "del" "Sfo"
 $ country: chr  "IN" "IN" "US"
 $ ip     :List of 3
  ..$ : raw  10 06 f5 2d ...
  ..$ : raw  42 e5 d7 6f ...
  ..$ : raw  7d 48 66 be ...
```

check if everything works

```
identical(df$fname, unlist(map(df$ip, decrypt)))
[1] TRUE
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(fname = c("aas", "asdw", "erf"), 
                     lname = c("das","gup", "fre"), 
                     city = c("Mum", "del", "Sfo"), 
                     country = c("IN", "IN", "US")), 
                .Names = c("fname", "lname", "city", "country"), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks @phiver. When trying the above code, i am getting values in df$name as "as.raw(c(0xa2, 0xbf, 0xe7, 0x7e, 0xf3, 0xad, 0x78, 0x5...". Please suggest how can this be converted to a "a2 bf e7 7e f3 ad 78..."

Comment: @eclairs, weird. Tried this code and different permutations of it on different machines and all works as it should be. Everything turns into `b2 a9 7d 3c dd...`. When you do `str(df)`, what do you see? you should see df$name defined as a list with raws like `b2 a9 7d 3c dd....`  as in above example.

Comment: for the as is columns, is gives me Factor, chr, Factor etc. But for the encrypted field it says: List of 10
  ..$ : raw  21 c4 59 f6 ...
  ..$ : raw  92 62 21 42 ...
  ..$ : raw  99 d1 12 54 ...

Comment: I tried the statement : df$name <- vapply(df$name, paste, collapse = "  ", character(1L))     Post this statement, the values in the dataframe are coming as required.

Comment: I would say the list is correct and more flexible. Because with using the `vapply.. ` you now have transformed your raws into chars and your decryption is no longer working.

Comment: Hi, Wanted to understand what parameter in R for AES256 encryption is to be used to change the SALT size?

Comment: @eclairs, someone can probably provide an answer. At the moment I have no idea. You should post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very late but checkout this package endecrypt

Installation :

```
devtools::install_github("RevanthNemani\endecrypt")
```

Use the following functions for column encryption:

```
airquality$Ozone <- EncryptCol(x = airquality$Ozone, pub.key = pubkey, encryption.type = "aes256")
```

For column decryption:

```
airquality$Ozone <- DecryptCol(x = airquality$Ozone, prv.key = prvkey, encryption.type = "aes256")
```

Checkout this [Github page](https://github.com/RevanthNemani/endecrypt)

Just remember to generate your keys and save it for first use. Load the keys when required and supply the key object to the functions

Eg

```
SaveGenKey(bits = 2048,
              private.key.path = "Encription/private.pem",
              public.key.path = "Encription/public.pem")

# Load keys already stored using this function 
prvkey <- LoadKey(key.path = "Encription/private.pem", Private = T)
```

It is very easy to use and your dataframes can be stored in a database or Rdata file.

Comment: This answer only points to a tool and doesn't provide a way to solve the problem. Please elaborate on it.